# How to include this SQL subquery for absolute number's value?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this query written for Access DB.

```
queryText = "SELECT Technicians.ID, firstName, lastName, Technicians.[Zone],
COUNT(technicianAssignedId) AS JobsDone, 
MAX(Faults.timeCompleted) AS LastJobTime,
MIN(Technicians.[Zone] - & faultZone &) AS Distance ' MIN has no use
FROM Technicians LEFT OUTER JOIN Faults ON
Technicians.ID = Faults.technicianAssignedID 
WHERE Specialization = '" & specialization & "'
`AND Availability = 'available' 
GROUP BY Technicians.ID, firstName, lastName, Availability,` Technicians.[Zone], Specialization 
ORDER BY 7 DESC"
```

I have this to get absolute value

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN value < 0 THEN value * -1
ELSE number *1 END
AS VALUE
FROM DB;
```

Now the column with Distance alias may end up as negative number which I need as positive  by using (* -1), but I can't figure out how to put this together.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why not just use the ABS(value) Function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
ABS(Technicians.[Zone] - & faultZone &) AS Distance
```

See [ABS doc](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/abs-funktion-HA001228718.aspx)

Comment: crap, I tried that before posting, it didn't work, I thought ABS() doesn't work with accces but it is working now...

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just use the absolute function, `ABS`?

Answer (score 1):

ABS() is working for all SQL versions